# How can I streamline my if...else statement so that it is more readable

Tags: c#

I have the method below that returns a `Scanner` object based on certain Ids.

It works, but the logic is getting complicated as I had more conditions.

Is there a way to make the `if...else` statement more streamlined and readable?

Here is my method:

```
public static Guid AssignScanner(int nationId, Guid uid9832Scanner, Guid uid7443Scanner, Guid cc7Scanner, Guid cc9Scanner, List<int> countryDate)
{
    if (nationId == 1994338999)
    {
        return uid9832Scanner;
    } 
    else if (countryDate.Contains(nationId))
    {
        return cc7Scanner;
    }
    else {
        if(nationId != 34637721)
        {
            return uid7443Scanner;
        }
    else
        {
            if(nationId == 348746376)
            {
                return cc7Scanner;
            }
        }
    }
    return Guid.Empty;
}
```

Thanks!

Skye

Comment: `if(nationId == 348746376)` will never be reached, because if `nationId == 348746376` then `nationId != 34637721` is also true

Comment: Use Guard clauses and drop the nesting which is unnecessary due to the `return`s.

Comment: Also, don't use magic numbers, such as `1994338999` and so on to define country codes, but use instead constants `const int FRANCE_ID = 123;`. Code will be more readable and maintainable

Comment: Just fixing formatting will help a lot.  First of all, the last `else` is at the **wrong** indentation level.  Second, you should be making use of `else if` over `else { if` everywhere.

Comment: @Mushroomator what is a `Guard` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another way is to represent each of the mapping logics as a predicate function and a value.

```cs
List<(Func<bool> Predicate, Guid Value)> mappings = new()
{
    ( () => nationId == 1994338999, uid9832Scanner ),
    ( () => countryDate.Contains(nationId), cc7Scanner ),
    ( () => nationId != 34637721, uid7443Scanner ),
    ...
    ( () => true, Guid.Empty ) //fallback logic
};
```

Here, I have used a list of `ValueTuple` instead of a `Dictionary` because I want to iterate through the collection in the order as I've defined its items. (As an alternative you can use [`OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=net-7.0) which guarantees the order while you are iterating but there is no generic version of this class.)

The usage of this is super simple

```
return mappings.First(m => m.Predicate()).Value;
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

> How does this List work?

The `List` class is a collection type. That means it can contain multiple items (whether it is a primitive like `int`/`string`/etc or complex type like tuples/user defined classes/etc.)

In this particular example the collection contains pairs.

- The "key" of the pair is a function to allow lazy evaluation of the condition.

  - The lazy in this context means we only execute the function if the preceding function did not return `true`
- The value is the associated `Guid` which will be used only if the related "key" is evaluated `true`

The very last item in the collection is a "catch-all". If none of the previous items' "key" are evaluated to `true` then this will be used.

> What is the Predicate?

A predicate is a function which returns with either `true` or `false`. Basically your `if` conditions are represented as functions (`() => {conditional expression}`)

> How do I find that?

Whenever you define a `ValueTuple` you can [name (give alias)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-assignment-and-deconstruction) to its items. If you don't then you can access them via `Item1`, `Item2`, etc..

In this particular example I named the pair's "key" to `Predicate` since it is a function which can return either `true` or `false`. I gave the alias `Value` to the value part of the pair.

Comment: How does this `List` work?  What is the `Predicate` and how do I find that?  thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I've added some explanation to my post, please check it again.

Answer (score 4):

Because you return the values, the rest of the if-statements won't be executed. This would be appropiate:

```cs
if (nationId == 1994338999)
{
    return uid9832Scanner;
} 

if (countryDate.Contains(nationId))
{
    return cc7Scanner;
}
    
if (nationId != 34637721) //This will now always be executed!
{
    return uid7443Scanner;
}
    
       
if (nationId == 348746376)
{
    return cc7Scanner;
}

return Guid.Empty;
```

See [Why I don't use the "else" keyword in my code anymore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ougvb8mT7k) by Nick Chapsas.

Answer (score 4):

Switch statements are always good

```
public static Guid AssignScanner(int nationId, Guid uid9832Scanner, Guid uid7443Scanner, Guid cc7Scanner, Guid cc9Scanner, List<int> countryDate)
{
    switch (nationId)
    {
        case 1994338999:
            return uid9832Scanner;
        case 348746376:
            return cc7Scanner;
        default:
            if (countryDate.Contains(nationId))
                return cc7Scanner;
            return uid7443Scanner;
    }
}
```

Comment: They are good if they reflect the original logic ;-)

Comment: I don't think this would work the same as my original if/else statement.  I am not sure if `default` is what I would need?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell this *definitely* won't work the same as your original if/else statement. I was more going for what seemed to be *intended* by your original if/else statement. Because as written you have a case that will *never* execute, which does not necessarily seem to have been intended.